# convert gmail api attachment string to photo

Tags: php, gmail-api

as [Gmail API instructed](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get), I requested attachment from

**GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/messageId/attachments/id**

and I received this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [size] => 10842
    [data] => _9j_4AAQSkZJR......
)
```

**Question:** How do I convert  `[data] => _9j_4AAQS.....` to a human readable image ?

in order to your test, the complete string is here below

```
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
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in Gmail API [reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments) Property `data` is of type `bytes`. Its Description says:

> The body data of a MIME message part as a base64url encoded string. May be empty for MIME container types that have no message body or when the body data is sent as a separate attachment. An attachment ID is present if the body data is contained in a separate attachment.

To get the file, use following code:

```
$data = strtr($data, array('-' => '+', '_' => '/'));

$fh = fopen(DOC_ROOT."/file.pdf", "w+");
fwrite($fh, base64_decode($data->data));
fclose($fh);
```

Hope it helps!